# SQL, like, after characters

Tags: sql, character

It's possible to do a LIKE SQL after some characters?

```
Exemple:

" Arthur is wanted : A test"

" Arthur is wanted : B"

" Arthur is wanted : BE COOL A"

" Arthur is wanted : ANSWER B"
```

I wanted "LIKE" sql after ":" with " A"
So, REGEX like should be return only the first and third sentence.
For the fourth sentence, i added " ANSWER" should not itself return because the regex is " A" and not " A%"

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply include the colon in your LIKE expression.

```
select *
from yourtable
where yourcolumn like '%:%A %'
OR  yourcolumn like '%:%A'
```

or, adjust your text slightly:

```
select *
from yourtable
where yourcolumn+' ' like '%:%A %'
```

Comment: but i could have " Arthur is wanted : B A" so, the words " A" is not the first.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it will work for your examples (the '%' between ':' and 'A' can match anything (can be B and space). have you tried?

Comment: Ok but for the fourth sentence (updated post), how do?

Comment: Haha, you move the goalpost! if you want A to be followed by a single space, just add that `LIKE '%:%A %'

Comment: " A" is in the end of the sentence. So no space. (updated post)

Comment: added that as an alternative

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247353/discussion-between-arthurarmand-and-tinazmu).

Comment: Ok good, thanks. Close.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Could you accept as answer?

Comment: Validate and done/close.